# How to change the format of date from YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM

Tags: python

I have a list of date in the format yyyy-mm-dd but I want to group them into a dictionary with the format yyyy-mm. Does anybody know how?

```
date_list = [
'2021-05-01', 
'2021-03-25', 
'2021-04-14',
'2021-04-18',
'2021-05-21',
'2021-05-17']
```

##### What I want

```
year_month = [
'2021-05',
'2021-03',
'2021-04',
'2021-04',
'2021-05',
'2021-05']
```

Comment: Can you give an example output that you're expecting?

Comment: Yep! Edited! Basically just somehow telling python to eliminate the 'DD' part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and easy solution is just to use string slicing

```
year_month = [date[:7] for date in date_list]
```